# Is a part of a measurable set (with "big cross-sections") measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P )$ be a probability space and $(U, \mathcal{U} )$ be a measurable space. Suppose $B \subset \Omega \times U$ is a $\mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{U}$-measurable set. Define $B_u := \{ \omega| (\omega,u) \in B\}$, 
$$A:= \{ u| \ \ P(B_u) > 1/2 \}.$$
Is $A$  $\ \ \mathcal{U}$-measurable? If not, is there any simple counterexample?

I tried to find a counterexample, but didn't succeed. I think that A is measurable, but don't know, how to prove it.

P.S. The problem is connected with a paper "Calcul stochastique dependant d'un parametre" (C. Stricker, M. Yor, 1978), proposition 1, p.113. In terms of this paper: the sequence $n_k(u)$ is $\mathcal{U}$-measurable, but it is not obvious and the proof of this fact, if I'm not mistaken, is connected with the question I asked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the section on product measures in Folland's  *Real Analysis* answers your question as "yes". Using the numbering from the first edition, with a blend of your notation and his:

**(2.36) Theorem.**  Suppose $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{N}, \nu)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. If $E \in \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$, then the functions $x \mapsto \nu(E_x)$ and $y \mapsto \mu(E_y)$ are measurable on $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

So how do we apply this in your situation? Take $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu) = (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{N}, \nu) = (U, \mathcal{U}, 0)$ where $0$ is the measure $0(C) = 0$ for all $C \in \mathcal{U}$. Both of these measures are $\sigma$-finite, since they are finite. Now let $E = B$; I believe in your notation $\mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{U} = \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{U}$, if these are both just the product $\sigma$-algebra (Folland uses $\otimes$ for the $\sigma$-algebra, reserving $\times$ for the set of "measurable rectangles" of the form $A \times B$).

The theorem now says, using your notation, that $u \mapsto P(B_u)$ is $(\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable, where $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, the preimage of $(1/2, \infty]$, which is your set $A$, is in $\mathcal{U}$ as desired.